# Search events created by me with FQL

Tags: events, facebook-fql

```
SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid 
FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid 
                         FROM event_member 
                         WHERE uid = me())
```

I feel that not only the event I created, but the event in which I have joined may be found by this query. I must not join an event which is unrelated for a test. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was clearly wrong. I'll try to see if I can find a better answer; if so, I'll repost a new one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add a creator filter to that outer query.

```
SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid 
FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid 
              FROM event_member 
              WHERE uid = me())
AND creator = me()
```